# WordPress - WooCommerce table relationships

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, entity-relationship

So i've been trying to get my head around this for a while now, but just can't seem to understand it.

I was wondering what the relationships were between the tables of the WooCommerce plugin in WordPress. You can see the image for the 7 individual tables.

Any help would be great just to help me understand how the WooCommerce tables communicate.

[image: WooCommerce Tables]

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: They aren't necessarily related to each other. They are just a place for WooCommerce to store datat that doesn't fit well into the posts or post meta tables.

Comment: Thats a good point. Thanks for getting back to me!